# SublimeText 2: Select lines that match search terms

Tags: expression, sublimetext2, selection, sublimetext, textselection

I need to select some lines inside of a list of file names to bring them at the end of the list.

Suppose I have Files.txt with this list:

```
filename1.aaa
filename1.bbb
filename1.ccc
filename2.aaa
filename2.bbb
filename2.ccc
filename3.aaa
filename3.bbb
filename3.ccc
```

I want to select all the lines where the file extension is `ccc` and then be able to CTRL-X and CTRL-V to put them on the bottom of the list.
So the result have to be like this:

```
filename1.aaa
filename1.bbb
filename2.aaa
filename2.bbb
filename3.aaa
filename3.bbb
filename1.ccc
filename2.ccc
filename3.ccc
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Windows press:

1. `Ctrl+F` for searching all ".ccc" terms in file;
2. `Ctrl+L` to expand selection to line;
3. `Ctrl+X` to cut all selected lines;
4. `End` to go at the end of your file;
5. `Ctrl+V` to past all selected line;

If you are using a Mac press `Command` instead of `Ctrl`.

This page could also help you: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection

Comment: I looked through a web search but didn't find anything. I didn't thought about the Sublime documentation... Thanks!

Comment: Use Alt+F3 to find all occurrences of the current word

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy in Sublime, select the extension .ccc on one of the lines and then press Alt+F3 to select all other matching occurrences of that selected text. Then press Ctrl+L to expand selection to the entire line, then cut and paste those lines elsewhere.